# How do I use JQuery to control popup with background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am having trouble making my image "30off" to open a background image and another image over the background image, I'm having problem after problem and for some reason can't get the 30off image to move over to the left no matter what box model type I use
HTML and Script:

```
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TESTGROUNDS</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="30offdiv">
<img id="30off" src="40off.jpg" width="140" height="80">
</div>
 <div id="sunbgdiv">
 <img id="sunbg" src="sunbg.gif" style="display:none;" width="100%">
</div>
 <div id="ytpaddiv">
 <a href="http://www.google.com"><img id="ytpad" src="YTPad.png" width="1200" height="482" style="display:none;"></a> 
</div>
<div id="xbtndiv">
  <img id="xbtn" src="close2.png" width="64" height="38" style="display:none;">
</div>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <P> testtesttesttest12312312testtesttest123123</P>
    <p>carcar</p>
    <p> </p>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
    <!-- Fade out Script -->
    <script>
    $(function(){

        $('#30off').on('click', function() {
         $('#sunbg').fadeIn();
        })

        $('#30off').on('click', function() {
         $('#ytpad').fadeIn();
        })

        $('#30off').on('click', function() {
         $('#xbtn').fadeIn();
        })

        $('#xbtn').on('click', function() {
         $('#xbtn').fadeOut();
        })

        $('#xbtn').on('click', function() {
         $('#sunbg').fadeOut();
        })

        $('#xbtn').on('click', function() {
         $('#ytpad').fadeOut();
        })


    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
    background-color:#0FF;
}

#30off
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 30%;
    width: 30%;
}

#xbtndiv{
    position:fixed;
    top: 34%;
    left: 14%;
}

#ytpaddiv{
    position:fixed;
    top: 34%;
    left: 14%;
}

#sunbgdiv{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -2px;
    left: -1px;
}
```

Stacks isn't displaying the code right

Comment: can you please create fiddle for same ?

Comment: @sachinkadam stacks is stackoverflow and I've fixed it now. what is fiddle?

Comment: Great you fixed it. jsFiddle is the perfect solution; it provides a custom environment (based on user selections) to test (or fiddle with) your JavaScript, HTML, and CSS code right inside your browser.